# Factors given by DoE can experimentally not be reached

Tags: experiment-design, chemometrics

We are running a [DoE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_experiments) in a [CCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_composite_design) manner at the moment.
One factor is quite difficult to reach and to reproduce: Humidity because it has to be set by chemical reactions.
To be more concise: The factor 56 % relative humidity can only be reached with 44 % relative humidity and some +/- % to reproduce it.

How to deal with that? My suggestion is to ignore that and kind of cheat the measurements by using the value 56 % for all the values which should be 56 %. I'd do this because in my understanding of the DoE it is less the value itself but more the factor that will be used. Sure, they are connected but in real experiments you will never be able to achieve all factors without any deviation.
Any advice?

The values are given here:

[image: Values]

```
A = H2 concentration
B = CO concentration
C = C2H2 concentration
D = Environment temperature
E = relative humidity
```

I can also ask for the actual DoE plan with all single measurement points? At the moment, I only receive the measured data on a dripping periodicity, so the first data points are not revealing the DoE. But I can ask for the plan.

Comment: Are we assuming that the experiments have already been performed? If not, why not just run at 44%? From the way it's phrased, it seems like an upper value. Another way is to use all your real values and depending on number of experiments,  perform a linear regression instead. Are any of the input factors correlated? That compromises the DOE

Comment: Kind of both, I also adviced to aim at the 44 % instead. Just wanted to know if it is valid in terms of the theoretical framework of a DoE where you will get the exact values you've to use?
Linear regression is also planned. Btw, what models come into mind when performing DoE?

Comment: Can you tell us which design you are using? Factorial designs tend to lead to box experimental regions, and if some corners must be cut (seems to be your case?) the design is no longer. Such designs should be starting points, not straighjackets ... One possibility is to use optimal design software (search this site, also D-optimality) to find a good design which do not enforce a box.

Comment: It's a CCD, how do I know whether the design is still valid? Thanks for the advices, will check it though I think for the moment it won't be applicable due to management decisions ;)

Comment: @Ben hard to tell without seeing the numbers.  Or maybe at least the coded values?

Comment: I added some values, is that helping?

Comment: Please add all the extra information in comments as an edit to the Q, not everybody reads comments!

Comment: I genuinely cannot interpret why you can't use 44% as your upper limit? Also, with so many constraints, maybe make some compromised by widening your ranges on the other factors and setting alpha to zero? Some sort of optimal design is a good shout. Or, just have "low" and "high" humidity as categorical factors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are finally analyzing the results of the experiment using some regression models. The situation seems to be that for the variable *humidity*, you cannot set the defined factor level exactly, but when set, you can measure it exactly?

If that is right, I can see no reason not to use it, in the analysis, as a numerical variable, using the measured value.

**EDIT**

Thinking a bit more about this, can there be some possible problems with this solution?  Write a stylized model as
$$ Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \epsilon_i $$  where $x_i$ is the chosen value in the design, which it in practice is difficult to reach. Then the realized model is
$$ Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 (x_i+\delta_i) + \epsilon_i $$
Now, if the chemical processes in the lab which makes it difficult to realize $x_i$, and in its place leads to $x_i+\delta_i$, impurities or whatever, is related to the experimental error $\epsilon_i$ (like impurities influencing both), so $\epsilon_i$  and $\delta_i$ is correlated? Then there is problems --- but since $\delta_i$ is known, this can be investigated, maybe by plotting $\delta_i$ and model residuals.

Comment: does this mean, it doesn't matter whether I can reach e.g. rH = 56 % or not? What if all my measurements are like this rH={42 %, 44 %, 56 %, 62 %, 76%), which relevance does this center point than have?

Comment: **WHY** is it impossible to reach it? Maybe if you can explain that, something more can be said.  Even an approximate center point would be useful. As long as the actually reached valued can be measured precisely, I stand with my answer

Comment: Because it is hard or even impossible to reach these points in the lab due to chemical processes. Even if it can be reached it is almost impossible to reproduce the same value. I'm not doubting you or your opinion, I only would like to understand the theory. Given your statement I conclude the center points are quite arbitrary resp. they are not really backed by theory? Simply spoken it is "Add a measurement in between"? I'm fine with that.

Comment: The argument with centerpoints is that, if you see it geometrically, they lie simultaneously on **all** the lines. So, with even only one centerpoint, you can get the possibility to check for curvature in **all directions**.